# Should the id tag be unique in checkbox forms?

Tags: html

According to freecodecamp in their [checkbox exercise](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/basic-html-and-html5/create-a-set-of-checkboxes)  all checkbox elements should have the same name and id, but according to [W3Schools the id should always be unique](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp). 
Freecodecamps forums seem to be down, which is why i'm asking here instead..

What is the correct answer?

Comment: `id`s should always be unique - w3 is correct

Comment: "All related checkbox inputs should have the same name attribute.", says your link. It does _not_ say they should have the same `id`, which would indeed be Bad (tm). The only mention of `id` is that it should match a label's `for` attribute.

Comment: Where does that exercise say all radio buttons should have the same id…?! You seem to be misunderstanding what it's saying.

Comment: id stands for identifier, it'd be a pretty poor identifier if it wasn't unique!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> According to freecodecamp in their checkbox exercise all checkbox elements should have the same name and id,

No. It says they should have the same *name*. It doesn't say they should have the same *id*. The example code shows the names are all the same and the ids are all different.

> but according to W3Schools the id should always be unique.

This is true.

> What is the correct answer?

Both. You're just misreading one of them.

---

An id must be unique in an HTML document. Period. There are no exceptions for checkboxes or radio buttons.